# Remove uncategorized from Permalink

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, permalinks

We are currently upgrading a shop from a hosted solution on big cartel to a wordpress e-commerce solution. So far it is going well, except for the product permalinks. From the products page, all links are in the form `/products/uncategorized/*product_name*`. How can I get it so that all it stops trying to put a category into the permalink? Sadly, it can't be avoided as there are already a large number of facebook likes, comments and other things that are based on the url being `/products/*product_name*` and changing to the new format will remove the likes count and comments.

Answer (score -1):

there is a plugin you can use that will strip the category base from the url

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

```
e.g. 
**myblog.com/products/uncategorized/*product_name** 
to 
**myblog.com/products/*product_name*
```